# How do I combine a dataframe with a spatial dataframe when receiving errors with both left_join and merge?

Tags: r, merge, left-join, r-sp

I am attempting to merge a dataframe containing data on hospital visits ("Hospital_Visits_df") with a shapefile/spatial*dataframe containing ZIP/ZCTA polygons and coordinates ("shp", downloaded from the [Census Bureau](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2018-2010-nation-u-s-2010-census-5-digit-zip-code-tabulation-area-zcta5-na)).

Both dataframes contain a matching column, `ZCTA` and `GEOID10`, respectively, though `shp` contains polygons for the entirety of the USA, which I will pare down to the relevant states later.

I have attempted using both `merge()` and `left_join()`, but both results in their own errors.

`shp_hospital_zip1 <- merge(shp, Hospital_Visits_df, by.x = "GEOID10", by.y = "ZCTA")`

> Error in .local(x, y, ...) : non-unique matches detected

But there are no duplicates in either column.

```
shp_hospital_zip2 <- shp@data %>% 
   left_join(Hospital_Visits_df, by = c("GEOID10" = "ZCTA"))
```

which appeared to work, except when I went to `summary(shp_hospital_zip2)` it no longer specifies it as a spatial data frame.

I am looking to merge my hospital visit data with the spatial data so that I can plot it with leaflet, but I am getting tripped up at the first step.

I appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you very much !!

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259803/merge-spatial-and-non-spatial-data-and-create-spatialpolygonsdataframe-in-r

Comment: Looking at this now. I will report back, thanks!

Comment: This did the trick, you wonderful person you! Thank you so much!! If you stick this down in an answer, I will give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rgdal)
mydf   <- read.csv("myCsv.csv")
myspdf <- readOGR("myShapefile.shp")

mynewspdf <- merge(myspdf, mydf, duplicateGeoms = T)
```

[Reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259803/merge-spatial-and-non-spatial-data-and-create-spatialpolygonsdataframe-in-r)

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to use `left_join()` on your sf-object directly, not on the @data part of your sf-object.

```
library(sf)

class(shp)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"

class(Hospital_Visits_df)
[1] "data.frame"

result <- shp %>% 
  left_join(Hospital_Visits_df)
```

Comment: `class(shp)` returns `[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"` and I am getting the expected error that I cannot join a dataframe with a spatial*dataframe.

Comment: did you load the library(sf) ?